# Streams + tasks missing inserts?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We've setup a stream on a table that is continuously loaded via snowpipe.

We're consuming this data with a task that runs every minute where we merge into another table. There is a possibility of duplicate keys so we use a ROW_NUMBER() window function, ordered by the file created timestamp descending where row_num=1. This way we always get the latest insert

Initially we used a standard task with the merge statement but we noticed that in some instances, since snowpipe does not guarantee loading in order of when the files were staged, we were updating rows with older data. As such, on the WHEN MATCHED section we added a condition so only when the file created ts > existing, to update the row

However, since we did that, reconciliation checks show that some new inserts are missing. I don't know for sure why changing the matched clause would interfere with the not matched clause.

My theory was that the extra clause added a bit of time to the task run where some runs were skipped or the next run happened almost immediately after the last one completed. The idea being that the missing rows were caught up in the middle and the offset changed before they could be consumed

As such, we changed the task to call a stored procedure which uses an explicit transaction. We did this because the docs seem to suggest that using a transaction will lock the stream. However even with this we can see that new inserts are still missing. We're talking very small numbers e.g. 8 out of 100,000s

Any ideas what might be happening?

Example task code below (not the sp version)

```
WAREHOUSE = TASK_WH
SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
WHEN SYSTEM$stream_has_data('my_stream')
AS
MERGE INTO processed_data pd USING (
  select 
  ms.*, 
  CASE WHEN ms.status IS NULL THEN 1/mv.count ELSE NULL END as pending_count, 
  CASE WHEN ms.status='COMPLETE' THEN 1/mv.count ELSE NULL END as completed_count
  from my_stream ms
  JOIN my_view mv ON mv.id = ms.id
  qualify
    row_number() over (
      partition by 
        id
      order by
        file_created DESC
    ) = 1
) ms ON ms.id = pd.id
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col1, col2, col3,...  )
                          VALUES (ms.col1, ms.col2, ms.col3,...)    
WHEN MATCHED AND ms.file_created >= pd.file_created THEN UPDATE SET pd.col1 = ms.col1, pd.col2 = ms.col2, pd.col3 = ms.col3, ....
;
```

Comment: Is it possible that this is somehow data related?  Maybe bad records that never actually got loaded via Snowpipe or have something funky on the `id`?  I think you are doing things correctly (shouldn't need the SP, either).  As a test, would it be possible to create a clone of your target table back prior to the load, and rerun the COPY and MERGE statements manually to see if the same records fall out?  This would eliminate the stream MERGE as being the issue.

Comment: @MikeWalton thanks for replying. The data was loaded correctly by Snowpipe as the pipe target table is what I am using to see what is missing. I haven't done a manual run but I did setup a parallel stream on the same table, that isn't consumed by a DML and I can see that the data is at least in this new stream. I assume it is reaching the other one too

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what is going wrong here, but the file created time related recommendation is given by Snowflake somewhere. It suggest that the file created timestamp is calculated in cloud service and it may be bit different than you think. There is another recommendation related to snowpipe and data ingestion. The queue service takes a min to consume the data from pipe and if you have lot of data being flown inside with in a min, you may end up this issue. Look you implementation and simulate if pushing data in 1min interval solve that issue and don't rely on file create time.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Apologies, I should have specified that the file creation time is created by our application and is at nanosecond precision to help eliminate duplicates. We also have an "ingest time" field which is simply current_timestamp in the pipe definition. Thing is, other rows with the same ingest time are inserted but for some reason, a few aren't. I'll double check load at the time of the missing data but I suspect it is busy at those times

Answer (score 0):

The condition `"AND ms.file_created >= pd.file_created"` seems to be added as a mechanism to avoid updating the same row multiple times.

Alternative approach could be using `IS DISTINCT FROM` to compare source against target columns(except id):

```
MERGE INTO processed_data pd USING (
  select 
  ms.*, 
  CASE WHEN ms.status IS NULL THEN 1/mv.count ELSE NULL END as pending_count, 
  CASE WHEN ms.status='COMPLETE' THEN 1/mv.count ELSE NULL END as completed_count
  from my_stream ms
  JOIN my_view mv ON mv.id = ms.id
  qualify
    row_number() over (
      partition by 
        id
      order by
        file_created DESC
    ) = 1
) ms ON ms.id = pd.id
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col1, col2, col3,...  )
                          VALUES (ms.col1, ms.col2, ms.col3,...)    
WHEN MATCHED 
 AND (pd.col1, pd.col2,..., pd.coln) IS DISTINCT FROM (ms.col1, ms.col2,..., ms.coln)
THEN UPDATE SET pd.col1 = ms.col1, pd.col2 = ms.col2, pd.col3 = ms.col3, ....;
```

This approach will also prevent updating row when nothing has changed.

Comment: Thanks! I added that condition to avoid updating rows with older updates, which was happening in some instances due to Snowpipe loading older data after more recent data. The difference in load times was enough for the older data to appear in a different run of the task. Unfortunately I think your suggestion would lead to the same issue